# How to get screenshot with Android phone bezel in Eclipse AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have an Android presentation coming up and would like to get some screenshots of my application.  Thing is, I'd like to have a screenshot of the phone with the app running on it.

I could use a camera and take a pic of a droid phone+app, but seems to me the AVD *used to* run inside a picture of the Nexus phone. Just wondering if it's an Eclipse config option somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - yes that is correct (simulated phone casing).  Running Eclipse Helios on Ubuntu Maverick 64. Motorola has an SDK add-on which gives a DroidX skin option when creating an AVD but they did some scaling which makes everything look terrible.  I'm just going to use a paint program for now (as someone suggested).  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using image editing software to superimpose the screenshot into an image of the phone. That's what the designers I work with do when they need to make PR screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

run the `DDMS` from the location where ever you have installed the Android and then chose Device menu and screen capture

Answer (score 2):

just do alt+printscreen  from keyboard keep in mind AVD is focused you will get screen shot of AVD..